# File/Folder naming & case conventions/standards for Web Applications

Tags: asp.net, naming-conventions, filenames

I've been searching google for recommendations on conventions or best practices when it comes to the 'case' and naming of files on folders within a Web Application.

Most of the time I work within Visual Studio, developing ASP.NET web applications. In the past I've always used PascalCase for all of my files and folders, with the exception of Javascript files which tended to be camelCase.

More recently I was wondering if it made more sense for everything to be lower-case so my Urls including the domain name were always lower case so my sites didn't have Url's like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Blog/AddPost.aspx
```

I'd also then not have any mixed case url's within the page for images, css etc.

Then I wondered, if I was to lowercase ALL the files/folders that were referenced via my site (including images, css, scripts etc) within my project, would I then go as far as to lowercase any of the other folders (e.g. App_Code, Controllers, Views, Models) & files (e.g. Globals.asax), within my project to prevent having a mix of naming conventions within my project as a whole?!

I know this probably isn't exactly a big deal, but I was interested to know if there were any recommendations or best practices out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders like App_Code are system folders so you leave them alone. I usually make my ASPX pages pascal case because it mirrors the convention of class naming. As for images and script folders, I really think that this is a matter of personal taste, or in-house convention.

Answer (score 1):

Because this makes little to no difference,  there are no such standards.

This is due to domains like `http://www.example.com` and `http://WWW.EXAMPLE.COM` resolve to the same thing.

You should use whatever convention that makes you happy, and if working in a team, one that the team agrees on.